# Exception on XML sorting

Tags: c#, xml, linq, exception, sorting

I'm trying to sort elements from an XML file in LINQ by an element's attribute:

```
public void SortXml()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
    XDocument datatemp = new XDocument(doc);

    doc.Descendants("Thing").Remove();
    var module = datatemp.Descendants("Thing").OrderBy(x => 
        (int)int.Parse(x.Attribute("ID").Value));
    doc.Element("Thing").Add(module);

    doc.Save(filename);
}
```

XML:

```
<Entry>
  <Properties>
    <Thungs Count="2">
      <Thing ID="1">
        <thing1 num="8" />
        <thing1 num="16" />
      </Thing>
      <Thing ID="31">
        <thing1 num="8" />
        <thing1 num="16" />
      </Thing>
    </Thungs>
  </Properties>
</Entry>
```

But in the line `doc.Element("Thing").Add(module);` I get a `NullReferenceException`.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to simplify it, why not go all the way?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var ordered = doc.Descendants("Thing")
                 .OrderBy(thing => thing.Attribute("ID").Value)
                 .ToList(); // force evaluation
doc.Descendants("Thing").Remove();
doc.Descendants("Thungs").Single().Add(ordered);
doc.Save(filename);
```

Answer (score 4):

`doc.Element("Thing")` will return `null`, because there are no elements called `"Thing"`: the `doc.Descendants("Thing").Remove();` call has removed them all. Even if it didn't, `XElement`'s `Element` method does not look at indirect descendants, so yo would need to supply the correct chain of element names leading to the element that you would like to modify.

Did you mean to write

```
doc.Element("Entry").Element("Properties").Element("Thungs").Add(module);
```

Comment: i thought about it, but no, result the same: nullreferenceexception(

Comment: @user1509821 Could you try `doc.Element("Properties").Element("Thungs").Add(module);`?

Comment: thanks you) it's work if
`doc.Element("Entry").doc.Element("Properties").Element("Thungs").Add(module);`

Comment: @user1509821 Great! I updated the answer to match the code that worked for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You even don't need to create two `XDocument` objects:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

        var query = from things in doc.Descendants("Thing")
                    orderby things.Attribute("ID").Value
                    select things;

        var orderedThings = query.ToList<XElement>();
        doc.Descendants("Thing").Remove();
        doc.Descendants("Thungs").First().Add(orderedThings);

        doc.Save(filename);
```

EDIT: If you know the "Path" within your XML-Schema it will be better to go with dasblinkenlight suggestion to use:

```
    doc.Element("Entry").Element("Properties").Element("Thungs").Add(orderedThings);
```

instead of the `Descendants("Thungs").First()` line.

Comment: `ToList<XElement>()`  can be written as `ToList()` because the type parameter is automatically inferred